# ViewPager + FragmentPagerAdapter inside a DialogFragment gets "IllegalArgumentException:No view found..."

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-nested-fragment

I am trying to show a FragmentDialog ( created and shown as a dialog NOT added as content in a view hierarchy) where there is a ViewPager whose content is given by a FragmentPagerAdapter (provides Fragments consisting of an image).

The code works perfect when showing ViewPager + FragmentPagerAdapter from a FragmentActivity, but get the following exception when doing it from a FragmentDialog:

"IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040077 for fragment SimpleFragment..."

Here is my code:

A SherlockFragmentActivity with a button to create and show the dialog.

```
public class BorrameActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.one_act);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showTheDialog();

        }});
   }

   private void showTheDialog(){
       AchGalleryDialog newFragment = AchGalleryDialog.newInstance(achs);
       newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
   }
```

The FragmentDialog:

```
public class AchGalleryDialog extends DialogFragment{
    public AchGalleryDialog(){  
}

    public static AchGalleryDialog newInstance(){       
        AchGalleryDialog f = new AchGalleryDialog();
        return f;       
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_user_result, container);
        getDialog().setTitle("Hola tronco");

        //content to show in the fragments
        int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.d1, R.drawable.d2, R.drawable.d3};

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyFragmentAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(),images);  
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the very simple MyFragmentPagerAdapter, 
I put only the getItem() method, and nullPointer checks:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return MySimpleFragment.newInstance(images[position]); 

}
```

And finally SimpleFragment:

```
public class SimpleFragment extends Fragment{
    int id;
    public static SimpleAchFragment newInstance(int imgId){
        SimpleFragment f = new SimpleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(ID_BUNDLE, imgId);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public SimpleAchFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.id = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(ID_BUNDLE) : 0;    
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_fragment, container, false);
        FragmentActivity mAct = getActivity();

        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        img.setImageDrawable(mAct.getResources().getDrawable(id));

        return v;
    }

}
```

More info, if the content passed to the adapter ( an int array with 3 ints) has length zero, then the adapter doesn't try to create any Fragment so dialogs appears correctly but empty (as expected). 
The Exception is thrown at SimpleFragment.onCreateView() at the time of inflating.
The id referenced in the exception (as not found) correspond to ViewPager 's id, with is properly defined in R.layout.simple_fragment.

I have try also to build the Dialog with an AlertDialog.builder and also directly with Dialog() contructor, but get the same behaviour.

Comment: I have the exact same problem... did you find any workarounds?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this:

In class **AchGalleryDialog**

```
MyFragmentAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),images);
```

instead of

```
MyFragmentAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(),images);
```

Because of this:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks 70sCommander, its great I became with this issue just a few days before than the new SDK arrived

Comment: No, problem ... having the same issue here and saw this post.

Comment: thanks a lot ! However, when i press back button, it closes everything including my parent fragment and container activity, any suggestions ?